# How do I target the first child that does not have a particular class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If I have the following html

```
<ul id="some_list">
    <li class="hide">Do Not Target This</li>
    <li class="hide">Do Not Target This</li>
    <li>Target This</li>
    <li>Do Not Target This</li>
</ul>
```

How do I target the first child that does not have the hide class? eg

```css
#some_list>li:not(.hide):first-child {
    color: #777;
}
```

But this doesn't work.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5G5ED/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use CSS [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) in order to select the first `li` element which doesn't have the `.hide` class:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5G5ED/2/)**.

```css
li:first-child:not(.hide),
li.hide + li:not(.hide) {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

Also consider checking the first list item (the first child) for existence of `.hide` class name.

Comment: But how about when there are multiple li with class name is not in order? http://jsfiddle.net/5G5ED/5/

Comment: @Sowmya Then you/he/she could override the CSS declarations by targeting the next list items like: `li:not(.hide) ~ li:not(.hide) { background-color: inherit; }`. **[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5G5ED/6/)**

Comment: but don't you think it is manual? I was wondering if we can get any direct method

Comment: @Sowmya Unfortunately, there's no `:first-of-class` or `nth-of-class` selector in CSS. Alternatively, you could use JavaScript/jQuery to achieve that.

Comment: @HashemQolami With the edit it is working, but could you explain why li:not(.hide) ~ li:not(.hide) is not also overriding the first part. It is selecting all visible siblings. Shouldn't that include the one we have applied a color to?

Comment: @SystemicPlural `A ~ B` is [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) which represents `B` element only if it is preceded by `A`. Therefore in this selector: `li:not(.hide) ~ li:not(.hide)` it won't select the first `li:not(.hide)` element.

Comment: `background-color: inherit` should be `background-color: transparent` instead if you decide to use an override. Backgrounds do not inherit by default (it doesn't make sense for them to do so).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
#some_list>li.hide + li:not(.hide){

    color: #CCC;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

using javascript you could do this

http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/5G5ED/4/

```
<script>
var parent = document.getElementById('some_list'),
    child = parent.getElementsByTagName('li');

child[2].style.color = 'blue';
</script>
```

Comment: I dont see any [tag:javascript] tag here

Comment: well, for starters, the script tags are Javascript and I have used Javascript to manipulate the style.